# how to prevent merge of unapproved pull requests in bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, devops, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

We are trying to improve our merge process by protecting specific branches from merge of any unapproved pull request.

The developer create a pull request and he/she can´t merge it until it is at least from one reviewers approved.

How to protect specific branches from such merges using Bitbucket api ? Or is there another way to achieve that goal ?

Thanks a lot in advanced

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Repository settings" (admin rights on the repo needed), then in "Pull requests", click on "Default reviewers"

[image]

Here you can set how many reviewers must give their approval for a pull request to be mergeable.

[image]

See the Atlassian help page about it [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/add-default-reviewers-to-pull-requests-834221295.html).

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I need in my question.

Comment: @Stefan I'm afraid you're right. This bitbucket web UI is specific and I realize it must be different from the one you have. Sorry for the noise, I let this here in the odd case it could help someone else later on.

Answer (score 1):

See https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/suggest-or-require-checks-before-a-merge/

Unfortunately the thing you want, aka enforce these rules, is only available in the premium plan.

[image: Bitbucket merge conditions]

Comment: THis is for the bitbucket cloud what about bitbucket server ?